# How to select date from datetime column?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a column of type "datetime" with values like 2009-10-20 10:00:00

I would like to extract date from datetime and write a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE datetime = '2009-10-20' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Is the following the best way to do it?

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN('2009-10-20 00:00:00' AND '2009-10-20 23:59:59')
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

This however returns an empty resultset. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 556, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
WHERE DATE(datetime) = '2009-10-20'
```

You could also try this:

`WHERE datetime LIKE '2009-10-20%'`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378572/3389737) for info on the performance implications of using `LIKE`.

Comment: tried this one : Where DATE(datetime) = '2009-10-20', it works

Comment: The first one is very slow and ignores the indexes. It is better to have LIKE 'date%'

Comment: WHERE DATE(datetime) LIKE '%keyword%'
its working, thanks

Comment: I believe this does not work as expected if the Rails timezone is something other than UTC. This is because DATE() resolves the column value to UTC. So a date such as "Fri, 30 Dec 2016 00:00:00 SGT +08:00" which we expect to find if we queried for "2016-12-30" will not be found. Why? Because DATE() will resolve it to its UTC equivalent before doing the comparism, which is "2016-12-29 16:00:00 UTC". Correct me if I am wrong as this was also a gotcha to me until recently.

Comment: WHERE DATE(datetime) = '{?sdate} works perfectly for a Crystal Reports parameter!  Nice work!

Comment: It is a performance killer and also floors the input date thereby considering everything between '2009-10-20 00:00:00' and '2009-10-20 23:59:59'

Comment: @Tikiboy - Rails stores DateTime and Time values in UTC (by default, out-of-the-box). So, if you haven't changed that default, simply make sure that the date you query for ("2016-12-30" in your example) is certain to be taken from a DateTime or Time object (use .to_date) that is in UTC. Problem solved.

Answer (score 131):

Using `WHERE DATE(datetime) = '2009-10-20'` **has performance issues**. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104364):

- it will calculate `DATE()` for all rows, including those that don't match.
- it will make it impossible to use an index for the query.

Use `BETWEEN` or `>`, `<`, `=` operators which allow to use an index:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2009-10-20 00:00:00' AND '2009-10-20 23:59:59'
```

---

**Update:** the **impact** on using `LIKE` instead of operators in an indexed column **is high**. These are some test results on a table with 1,176,000 rows:

- using `datetime LIKE '2009-10-20%'` => 2931ms
- using `datetime >= '2009-10-20 00:00:00' AND datetime <= '2009-10-20 23:59:59'` => 168ms

When doing a second call over the same query the difference is even higher: 2984ms vs 7ms (yes, just 7 milliseconds!). I found this while rewriting some old code on a project using Hibernate.

Comment: Interesting, if MySql implementation automatically converts `DATE(datetime)` to `BETWEEN AND ` behine the scenes we get short statement and cool performance. Why not? Why they did not do this? :)

Comment: Because something like `DATE(datetime) in (:list)` doesnt work with `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 33):

You can format the datetime to the Y-M-D portion:

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: And this way you can get only the time part if needed: `DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%H:%i:%S')`

Comment: this works great formating the datetime but in return the database will return a new array to set the name for it just ad the desired name in the end   DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%Y-%m-%d') arrayName   for more details check  documentations https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 20):

Though all the answers on the page will return the desired result, they all have performance issues. **Never perform transformations on fields in the `WHERE` clause (including a `DATE()` calculation) as that transformation must be performed on all rows in the table.**

The `BETWEEN ... AND` construct is inclusive for both border conditions, requiring one to specify the 23:59:59 syntax on the end date which itself has other issues (microsecond transactions, which I believe MySQL did not support in 2009 when the question was asked).

**The proper way to query a MySQL `timestamp` field for a particular day is to check for Greater-Than-Equals against the desired date, and Less-Than for the day after, with no hour specified.**

```
WHERE datetime>='2009-10-20' AND datetime<'2009-10-21'
```

This is the fastest-performing, lowest-memory, least-resource intensive method, and additionally supports all MySQL features and corner-cases such as sub-second timestamp precision. Additionally, it is future proof.

Comment: And, using your performance argument, are the ">=" and "<" equally calculated on each row of the table, or the SQL server just "magically" knows if a number is greater than other? :-)

Comment: @JavierGuerrero: My example compares two constants: One from the table and a string literal.

Comment: The "one from the table" is not a constant, it varies for each row, so the same calculation has to be done for each row (and also, both have to be converted to epoch time to perform the comparison)

Answer (score 14):

## Here are all formats

Say this is the column that contains the `datetime` value, table `data`.

```
+--------------------+
| date_created       |
+--------------------+
| 2018-06-02 15:50:30|
+--------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select DATE(date_created) from data;
+--------------------+
| DATE(date_created) |
+--------------------+
| 2018-06-02         |
+--------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select YEAR(date_created) from data;
+--------------------+
| YEAR(date_created) |
+--------------------+
|               2018 |
+--------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select MONTH(date_created) from data;
+---------------------+
| MONTH(date_created) |
+---------------------+
|                   6 |
+---------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select DAY(date_created) from data;
+-------------------+
| DAY(date_created) |
+-------------------+
|                 2 |
+-------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select HOUR(date_created) from data;
+--------------------+
| HOUR(date_created) |
+--------------------+
|                 15 |
+--------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select MINUTE(date_created) from data;
+----------------------+
| MINUTE(date_created) |
+----------------------+
|                   50 |
+----------------------+
```

---

```
mysql> select SECOND(date_created) from data;
+----------------------+
| SECOND(date_created) |
+----------------------+
|                   31 |
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
DATEDIFF ( day , startdate , enddate ) = 0
```

Or:

```
DATEPART( day, startdate ) = DATEPART(day, enddate)
AND 
DATEPART( month, startdate ) = DATEPART(month, enddate)
AND
DATEPART( year, startdate ) = DATEPART(year, enddate)
```

Or:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), startdate, 105)) = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), enddate, 105))
```

Answer (score 5):

simple and best way to use date function

example

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE date(datetime) = '2009-10-20'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM 
data 
WHERE date(datetime ) >=   '2009-10-20'  && date(datetime )  <= '2009-10-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `date(tscreated) = '2022-06-04'` on a large record set.  My tscreated is indexed. It took 42 seconds.

I then tried `tscreated >= '2022-06-04' and tscreated < '2022-06-05'` and the time was .094 sec.

I realize that the record set might be in memory the second time, but I also believe that the date function negates the value of the index.

Answer (score -6):

Well, using `LIKE` in statement is the best option 
`WHERE datetime LIKE '2009-10-20%'` 
it should work in this case