# MySQL SELECT WHERE datetime matches day (and not necessarily time)

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a table which contains a datetime column.  I wish to return all records of a given day regardless of the time.  Or in other words, if my table only contained the following 4 records, then only the 2nd and 3rd would be returned if I limit to 2012-12-25.

```
2012-12-24 00:00:00
2012-12-25 00:00:00
2012-12-25 06:00:00
2012-12-26 05:00:00
```

Comment: See answer by John Woo at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769026/mysql-select-where-timestamp-today

Answer (score 425, accepted):

**NEVER EVER** use a selector like `DATE(datecolumns) = '2012-12-24'` - it is a performance killer:

- it will calculate `DATE()` for all rows, including those, that don't match
- it will make it impossible to use an index for the query

It is much faster to use

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59'
```

as this will allow index use without calculation.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Used_By_Already, in the time since the inital answer in 2012, there have emerged versions of MySQL, where using '23:59:59' as a day end is no longer safe. An updated version should read

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname >='2012-12-25 00:00:00'
AND columname <'2012-12-26 00:00:00'
```

The gist of the answer, i.e. the avoidance of a selector on a calculated expression, of course still stands.

Comment: I was about to comment that a1ex07's solution seems not near as good as the others.  After reading your post, maybe I need to reverse my thinking!

Comment: Just tested on two servers the above is MUCH (10x at least) faster than date()='' especially for huge tables. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it enough to say *and 2012-12-26*? The date is automatically assumed to be at the time 0 (i.e. 00:00:00.000) and the upper bound is exclusive. Or am I just being confused?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I used a very verbose way to phrase the query to make it more readable and drive home my point, a.o.t. refining it. The answer by a1ex07 has the sparse syntax.

Comment: @EugenRieck what if I also needed to get the time in a different timezone?

Comment: @majidarif Use `CONVERT_TZ()` on the constant arguments to care for the time offset.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Better yet: `WHERE col >= '2012-12-25' AND col < '2012-12-25' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.  It avoids 0 time and works for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`, etc.  And deals with leap-day, etc.

Comment: '2012-12-25 23:59:59' is NOT VALID as an end-of-day, it was always a bad idea and it will cause bugs for versions of MySQL that support sub-second time precision. Much better to use the approach by Rick James (above) or a1ex07 (other answer)

Comment: @Used_By_Already You do realize, that at the time of the answer in 2012 there was no sub-second MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I realise that, and I would have had the same feeling about this answer at that point (It is the same as Oracle's "date" data type). 23:59:59 is NOT the end of a "calendar day", never has been and never will be. The added problem is that these "venerated answers" can still get referred to without due consideration of relevance years later.

Comment: what about `MONTH(datecolumn)` and `YEAR(datecolumn)`? are those performance killers too?

Comment: @dapidmini They are indeed. The important part is, that a calculation has to be applied to ALL values of that column in the table, rendering any index useless.

Comment: @TusharBanne Do you mean 'NOW()' amd friends with "sysdate"? If yes, the performance is fine: MySQL evaluates those functions once, at the begin of the query, and then treats them as constants.

Comment: Incase one is using java 8 to search for the date, you can use java 8 method: plusDay (long days )to increase the date from 25 to 26.
Example: currentDay.plusDay(1L);

Answer (score 42):

`... WHERE date_column >='2012-12-25' AND date_column <'2012-12-26'` may potentially work better(if you have an index on date_column) than `DATE`.

Comment: I actually wonder what is faster - this or the `BETWEEN` solution ... anybody bechmarked?

Comment: It shouldn't be any difference . `BETWEEN` is just a way to write `field >= value1 and fied<= value2`.

Comment: Note that per the MySQL Manual:

"For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE."

So unless they are all the same type, it is best to explicitly cast them.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM datetable WHERE datecol LIKE '2012-12-25%'
```

Comment: LIKE seems to be as slow as DATE(datetimecol). Better use Eugen's or a1ex07's solution.

Comment: It's not always about speed. So I like this solution. It's much more readable.

Comment: Why would you want to use this? When storing dates, you'd want to store it as a datetime value and you can just search `WHERE datecol = '2012-12-25'`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where Date(col) = 'date'
```

Comment: for example where 'date' can be 2012-12-25  and (col) is your column

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to what Eugene Ricks said. If one is using spring data/jpa with Java 8 and above you can use plusDays(long hours) to increase day 25 to 26.

Example:

```
LocalDateTime lowerDateTime=LocalDateTime.parse("2012-12-25T00:00:00");
LocalDateTime upperDateTime = lowerDateTime.plusDays(1l);
System.out.println("my lowerDate =="+lowerDateTime);
System.out.println("my upperDate=="+upperDateTime);
```

Comment: I mearnt Eugene Rieck not Ricks