# Return all records for given week

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to return all records for the 5th week of 2012.  For instance, the following query would provide the correct records, however, is very inefficient as WEEK() and YEAR() must be calculated for each row and indexes can't be used.  I expect BETWEEN should be used, but I am not sure how I would do so.  I also need to do something similarly for a given month and quarter, and ideally could use a similar solution.  If need be, I could supplement the SQL with PHP.  Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE WEEK(dateColumn)=5 AND YEAR(dateColumn)=2012;
```

EDIT - THE FOLLOWING HAS BEEN ADDED TO SUPPLEMENT COMMENTS

*** *TEST DATA* *****

```
SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE award_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-08'
```

0.55236601829529

```
SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE YEAR(award_date)=2012 AND WEEK(award_date)=5
```

0.52925586700439

```
SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE award_date > STR_TO_DATE('1,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y') AND award_date < STR_TO_DATE('0,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y')
```

0.69798302650452

*** *TEST SCRIPT* *****

```
//$sql ="SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE award_date BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-08'";
//$sql ="SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE YEAR(award_date)=2012 AND WEEK(award_date)=5";
$sql ="SELECT * FROM projects_sell WHERE award_date > STR_TO_DATE('1,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y') AND award_date < STR_TO_DATE('0,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y')";

$current_time=microtime(true);
for ($i=1; $i<=1000; $i++)
{
    $stmt = db::db()->query($sql);
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo($sql.'<br>'.(microtime(true)-$current_time).'<br>');
```

Comment: Did you benchmark it and found it is too slow?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to determine the bottlenecks. However, regardless PHP will be slower than MySQL in this case.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I could if needed.  Guess I just believed those who say it is very inefficient.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time

Answer (score 1):

Using `STR_TO_DATE` you can create the first and last day of a week. Then use `BETWEEN` or date arithmetic to find the dates:

```
WHERE dateColumn > STR_TO_DATE('1,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y') 
               AND dateColumn < STR_TO_DATE('0,5,2012', '%w,%v,%Y')
```

Comment: Will this not create the same inefficiencies as using WEEK() and YEAR()?

Comment: Perhaps. You could use variables (either in code or in MySQL) to preprocess them.

Comment: Otoh, I suppose MySQL does some caching and compiling before running queries. Benchmark to be sure.

Comment: I am currently creating a test, and will post the results in a few minutes.

Comment: You were right;  Always test.  Appears that using YEAR() is the most efficient.  Granted, it wasn't a huge table.  I will make a bigger table, and provide update if results change.

Comment: Made a big table.  All solutions too a long time. Then added an index on date, and the BETWEEN solution was fast.  Your didn't provide any results, and I think it was just a minor error, but haven't yet figured it out.

Comment: Probably, my format string is incorrent. Check the docs for details on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you could figure out the beginning date and the end date of the fifth week, and filter based on the BETWEEN operator

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE T.Date1 BETWEEN '01-29-2012 00:00:00' AND '02-04-2012 00:00:00'
```

Comment: How can a question be an answer?