# How to select rows that have current day's timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am trying to select only today's records from a database table.

Currently I use

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`timestamp` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

But this takes results for the last 24 hours, and I need it to only select results from today, ignoring the time. How can I select results based on the date only ?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

use `DATE` and `CURDATE()`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()
```

**Warning! This query doesn't use an index efficiently**. For the more efficient solution see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14769096/285587)

[see the execution plan on the DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72440/2)

Comment: See the difference: [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1362b/2) Notice the FILTERED = 25 in the 2nd query.

Comment: @ypercube oh i missed that but i was wondering why is the value on extra `Using where; Using index`?

Comment: The index is used to select the rows. But the whole index is scanned (and all values are converted with DATE() to evaluate the condition) with your query. I'll update my answer with a better example.

Comment: Check how the index may not be used in your query, if there are many rows (and other columns).

Comment: with all due respect, ypercube solution is better for performance reasons, if your table has hundreds of thousands of lines, you should definitely go in this direction

Comment: the `` are important because `timestamp` (and `date` as in my case) is a MySQL reserved word

Comment: The answer by ypercubeᵀᴹ is better than this one -- because of being able to use an index.

Answer (score 75):

If you want an index to be used and the query not to do a table scan:

```
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
  AND timestamp < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

To show the difference that this makes on the actual execution plans, we'll test with an **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3def7/1)** (an extremely helpful site):

```
CREATE TABLE test                            --- simple table
    ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`timestamp` datetime                    --- index timestamp
    , data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
          DEFAULT 'Sample data'
    , PRIMARY KEY (id)
    , INDEX t_IX (`timestamp`, id)
    ) ;

INSERT INTO test
    (`timestamp`)
VALUES
    ('2013-02-08 00:01:12'),
    ---                                      --- insert about 7k rows
    ('2013-02-08 20:01:12') ;
```

Lets try the 2 versions now.

---

Version 1 with **`DATE(timestamp) = ?`**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE()            ---  using DATE(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp ;
```

**Explain:**

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE  TABLE  TYPE  POSSIBLE_KEYS  KEY  KEY_LEN  REF 
1   SIMPLE       test   ALL

ROWS  FILTERED  EXTRA
6671  100       Using where; Using filesort
```

It **filters all (6671) rows** and then does a filesort (that's not a problem as the returned rows are few)

---

Version 2 with **`timestamp <= ? AND timestamp < ?`**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
  AND timestamp < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY timestamp ;
```

**Explain:**

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE  TABLE  TYPE  POSSIBLE_KEYS  KEY  KEY_LEN  REF 
1   SIMPLE       test   range t_IX           t_IX    9 

ROWS  FILTERED  EXTRA
2     100       Using where
```

It uses a **range scan on the index**, and then reads only the corresponding rows from the table.

Comment: great explanation and thanks for the sql-fiddle. one comment on your schema that threw me for a moment, that `INDEX t_IX (timestamp, id)` could (should?) just be `INDEX t_IX (timestamp)`, as the primary key is implied in the index. or is there a reason i don't understand for doing that? i tried it in sql-fiddle and saw the same (better) execution plan

Comment: @natbro Yes, if the table uses the InnoDB engine, the `id` (because it is the PK and thus the clustered index of the table) is appended in the index anyway. So, it doesn't hurt to explicitly add it (and it may catch some optimizer blind spots). It's certainly not relevant in this case/query.

Comment: Can anyone explain why `timestamp < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` is necessary?

Comment: @Nightwolf because you may have rows stored where the timestamp value is in the future. The question asks for *"only today's records"*.

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ Aha, did not consider that purely because timestamp will not do future dates. Nonetheless good point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE timestamp >= CURDATE()
```

it is shorter , there is no need to use 'AND timestamp < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY'

because CURDATE() always return current day

[MySQL CURDATE() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp)

Comment: a) The question asks for "only today's records", and your code get also future dates.
b) Your comparison don't work, you must do it with DATE(timestamp)

In other words: If you fix your answer, you'll obtain @JohnWoo original answer.

Comment: it is "shorter" to write but **whole world**  slower to execute

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use the CURRENT_DATE alternative, with the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE created >= CURRENT_DATE
```

[Examples from database.guide](https://database.guide/curdate-examples-mysql/)

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to compare with a particular date , You can directly write it like :**

```
select * from `table_name` where timestamp >= '2018-07-07';
```

// here the timestamp is the name of the column having type as timestamp

*or*

**For fetching today date , CURDATE() function is available , so :**

```
select * from `table_name` where timestamp >=  CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be the easiest in my opinion:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` like concat(CURDATE(),'%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast it to a date:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CAST(`timestamp` TO DATE) == CAST(NOW() TO DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

How many ways can we skin this cat?  Here is yet another variant.

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) = '2015-11-18';

Answer (score 0):

On Visual Studio 2017, using the built-in database for development I had problems with the current given solution, I had to change the code to make it work because it threw the error that DATE() was not a built in function.

Here is my solution:

`where CAST(TimeCalled AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: You probably were not using MySQL but some other DBMS (SQL Server perhaps?) Notice the tags of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column_with_unix_time,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```