# fetch rows that matches today timestamp in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql  with three fileds

```
id
name
time_stamp
```

here `time_stamp` stores php `time()` value.

I want to get the fields that matches todays timestamp ,now i am fetching  all rows and check time stamp condition in the loop if it matches  will print the current row.

Is there anyway to do this in mysql query itself?

Comment: What code have you tried still. Post that so that it will be useful for us to Ensure progress to you.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769026/mysql-select-where-timestamp-today

Comment: You should go for `SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE DATE('time_stamp') = NOW()`

Comment: @BarneyStinson empty rows

Comment: @BarneyStinson i am using php `time()` to store the time_stamp value

Comment: @BlessanKurien Please update your question and add at least one row from your the table.

Comment: If you are doing so then above query won't work because it will check perfect time with seconds you can try `SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE DATE('time_stamp') like concat(CURDATE(),'%')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you insert unix timestamps (`time()`), you don't need to fetch all rows and make a comparison on the fetching. Just use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`time_stamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16d5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`.

So, there's one way:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`time_stamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()`  <sub>@Ghost already posted this in his answer</sub>

But one potential problem with this approach is that you cannot make use of index (if any) on `time_stamp` column.

Here's the other way around:

```
SELECT * FROM 
table_name
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOW() or Currentdate() function for that

Answer (score 0):

You can do a between in database to get records from today for example, or you can convert date to the specific format that you need.

to human-readable you can use http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

if is the case use between with date_format and select only what you need.

i hope help you