# How to query db and select from where PHP datetime is today

Tags: php, datetime

I have data inserted into table 'dnt' with colum `date` being php datetime.

```
$date = time();// this was inserted into the db as :1481811673
$today =  time();
"SELECT * FROM `dnt` WHERE 'date' = '$today'";
```

Comment: Is "date" column ? in ur table ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT \* WHERE timestamp = TODAY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769026/mysql-select-where-timestamp-today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a timestamp with date today as timestamp changes per second so to compare right, you need to convert the timestamp stored in db into a dateformat and then compare that date with today date. You can do it as follows:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); // date today in format - YYYY-mm-dd
//your query
"SELECT * FROM `dnt` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(dnt.date), '%Y-%m-%d') = '$today'";
```

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 1):

This appears to answer your question http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/mysql-select-from-table-where-date-today/

tldr;

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())`

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple:

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM `dnt` WHERE 'date' = '".date('Y-m-d')."'";
```

To work with a timestamp:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$stmt = "SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date = '".$now->getTimestamp()."'";
```

#### Detail

What the above query does is to `SELECT` all (*) `FROM` table `dnt` `WHERE` date =

the `date()` function in PHP returns a certain date based on the parameters you put in. the `Y` is for the years, the `m` for the months and the `d` for the days. So it will become `date('Y-m-d')` which will return 2010-01-01 for example.

the `'".` and `."'` are to escape the php function so that it will not give you any syntax errors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how `date` field of DB which is a time stamp(like: 345635234) that is integer can be compared with `date(Y-m-d)` which is string(like: 2016-12-12) ?

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Peter said - the query is incorrect. You are comparing the **date** string value (`date` between single quotes) to a timestamp.

`` $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `dnt` WHERE `date` = '".date('Y-m-d')."'"; ``