# Is it slow to use the PHP date() func to compare with SQL datetime fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, lamp

I have this website where I a user can create so many posts a day called 'clippets' and before I check the limit, I've used some SQL to get the total number of 'clippets' in the current day.

So let's say I only want to allow users to make 20 'clippets' a day, not based on time though only the day, as if I were to base it on the last 24 hours it would be like the user is chasing the limit all the time...

Anyway, here is my SQL:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM clippets WHERE userID = ? AND DATE(createdAt) = '$date'; ";
```

My question is... Is this a slow way to approach this, using the PHP date function and then using that within the SQL query, does it treat them as strings or? Because the createdAt field is a datetime data type, so does MySQL convert both dates to strings and then compare? Is that a slow way of doing this?

Comment: Why not testing it by yourself? Use microtime() before and after each case and comparing them?

Comment: @OfirBaruch is the use of `microtime()` slow ?

Comment: Have you tried to use mysql function NOW() ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I meant that he should use microtime() in both cases in order to test the efficiency of the his code. Or you're being sarcastic?

Comment: But with createdAT being a datetime in the DB and date() being a string, what happens, does the DB convert both to strings or...?

Comment: @Erdss4 I think you should just try to do some test by yourself. SO is for having help when you tried and get stuck.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I think Yves was being sarcastic ;) I hope.

Comment: @OfirBaruch misguided sarcasm, that all. Could be slower than `nanotime()` though :)

Comment: The meddle of jokes, sarcasm, indirection, premature optimization and misguided helpfulness of these few comments is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not convert both dates to strings for the comparison. It converts the string to a date once, and uses that for all the other comparisons. Passing a date parameter as a string is standard practice and trying to do something else instead will not be a good source of optimization.

However, if you're only interested in the current date, you don't need to pass a parameter for the date at all. You can use MySQL date functions to select the rows you need. One of the approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182275/datetime-equal-or-greater-than-today-in-mysql) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769026/mysql-select-where-timestamp-today) should work.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM clippets WHERE userID = ? AND createdAt >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, filtering on function results is slower than filtering on fields, particularly so with indexed field.  If your datatype includes the time, your filter should resemble this:

```
where createdAt >= yourDateVariable
and createdAt < the day after yourDateVariable
```