# Having a problem getting only records from today in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table set up with these types
Columns:

```
Date_Time datetime PK 
ppm2      int 
ppm10     int 
aqi       int
```

the query I am using is

`SELECT * FROM aqi_data where Date_Time = CURDATE()`

This returns 0 records

```php
<?php $chartQuery = "SELECT * FROM aqi_data where Date_Time = CURDATE()"; 
$chartQueryRecords = mysqli_query($con, $chartQuery); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chartQueryRecords)){ 
  echo "'".$row['Date_Time']."',".$row['aqi']. 
       ",".$row['ppm2'].",".$row['ppm10']."],"; 
} ?>
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Please share some sample codes, so someone can relate to the real scenario & can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <?php
                     $chartQuery = "SELECT * FROM aqi_data where Date_Time = CURDATE()";
                     $chartQueryRecords = mysqli_query($con, $chartQuery);
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chartQueryRecords)){
                           echo "['".$row['Date_Time']."',".$row['aqi'].",".$row['ppm2'].",".$row['ppm10']."],";
                        }
                     ?>

Comment: are you passing date with time ? Date time column contains time also...and you have to just compare  date. After removing time parameter, check the format also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows that have current day's timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769026/how-to-select-rows-that-have-current-days-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

You have stored **DateTime** and you are comparing with **date**.  One way is to cast the data as date

```php
<?php 
$chartQuery = "SELECT * FROM aqi_data where CAST(Date_Time AS DATE) = CURDATE()"; 
$chartQueryRecords = mysqli_query($con, $chartQuery); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chartQueryRecords)){ 
  echo "'".$row['Date_Time']."',".$row['aqi']. 
       ",".$row['ppm2'].",".$row['ppm10']."],"; 
} ?>
```

Another way, which will be faster is to compare Date_Time with a range between **CURDATE** and **CURDATE + 1DAY**.

```php
"SELECT * FROM aqi_data where Date_Time >= CURDATE() and Date_Time < CURDATE()+1";
```

**Not Tested !**

Comment: 0 records returned

Comment: For some unknown reason, everything I try returns nothing

Comment: Have you tried a print_r ($chartQueryRecords).  And does $con have a value ?

Comment: If I use SELECT * FROM aqi_data it shows all records just fine

Comment: Maybe there are no records for today

Comment: Did that work for you ?