# MySQL query value where current date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

What is the proper way to query all data on current date? a function in mysql that will get the current date in 12:01 am and  current date  11:59  pm

```
select * from tb_data where date between currentdate_starts and currentdate_ends
```

Comment: ` DATE(column) = CURDATE()` is a performance killer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using CURDATE()

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE DATE(column) = CURDATE()


select * from tb_data where DATE(date) = CURDATE()
```

Documentation: [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Answer (score 5):

Without using `DATE(column) = CURDATE()`

```
   SELECT * FROM tb_data WHERE date between concat(curdate(),' ','00:00:00') AND concat(curdate(),' ','23:59:59')
```

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time)

Answer (score 2):

CURDATE() returns the current date.

```
SELECT * from FROM tb_data WHERE DATE(column) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**CURRENT_DATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) or [**CURDATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_data WHERE DATE(dateCol) = CURRENT_DATE();
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM tb_data WHERE DATE(dateCol) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

well since there are so many answers. Try this one too and see if it's faster

```
SELECT * FROM tb_data WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY-INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```