# MySQL search record in table by DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

I`ve created this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
   id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   title VARCHAR ( 15 ) NOT NULL,
   description TEXT NOT NULL,
  _type VARCHAR ( 15 ) NOT NULL,
  date_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  location VARCHAR ( 15 ) NOT NULL
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Then i have inserted some records in the table,one of them has DATETIME field 2014-04-04 00:00:00. What i want is to search this  record by it`s DATETIME field. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE date_time = 2014-04-04;
```

But this query returns:

```
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why this isn`t working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to get the date portion of the datetime string for comparison (and put quotes around your date string):

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2014-04-04';
```

Comment: Hey Jon, can you comment on the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time)? I was about to flag this as a dupe and it recommends against your answer of using `DATE`

Comment: Worked ! Sorry for the silly question and thanks.. :)

Comment: @Andy That would be a better practice then what I answered here.

Answer (score 1):

An option you have is

```
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2014-04-04 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-04 23:59:59'
```

The advantage of using this over the `WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2014-04-04'` answer, is that when using the `DATE` function (as mentioned by Eugine Reick in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104364/189134))

- it will calculate DATE() for all rows, including those, that don't match
- it will make it impossible to use an index for the query

Thus, if your table is small and not expected to grow significantly, the `DATE` answer will work for you. However, if you are expecting a large volume of data, performance will deteriorate. It is better to use the `BETWEEN` option.

Comment: Yes, i`ve tried this and it worked. One more little question - how can i search only by day for example ?