# Hotel Monthly bookings grouped by Hotel ID and Hotel name

Tags: mysql

I need help with a MySQL String that I can use every month to generate a tabular monthly report for my online booking system showing report title as "Total Hotel Bookings for yyyy-mm-dd, and having the Hotel ID sequentially in the first column (starting with 1000, 1001,etc increments by 1), Hotel name in the second column, City in column 3, State in column 4, e-mail address in column 5, and  total umber of bookings for the month in column 6.

In my MySQL database I have a table called sales and it has the following database structure for the key variables:

```
FIELDS          TYPE        Notes

hotelid         VARCHAR(5)  Property ID (these are all digits)


hotelname       VARCHAR(35) Property name


booked          DATE        Date booked in yyyy-mm-dd format


ref             VARCHAR(16) Booking reference (alphanumeric e.g. Booking12345)


numitems        TINYINT(4)  Number of items


itemno                      Item number


city            VARCHAR(40)


state           VARCHAR(40)


email           VARCHAR(70)
```

The string I have is not appropriate for my requirements is given below:

`“SELECT SUM(??), SUM(??) FROM sales WHERE arrdate>=’??’ AND depdate>=’??’ AND propid=??`” We would replace ?? with the fields or data which would depend on what we wanted to retrieve.

Please help  me with a String that can be used immediately I get it.
Thanks. Velox

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- using [between in your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time), i.e. `WHERE columname BETWEEN '2014-07-04 00:00:00' AND NOW()`
- using an unsigned int instead of a date and therefore timestamps, i.e.  `WHERE columname BETWEEN '".$yourNumericTimestamp."' AND '".time()."'` (php)

I usually use timestamps since they give me less headache with formatting.

Note that if you're not 110% sure that `$yourNumericTimestamp` is numeric you have to wrap it with `$db->real_escape_string($yourNumericTimestamp)`.

EDIT: Too match your example query:
`SELECT SUM(??), SUM(??) FROM sales WHERE arrdate BETWEEN ’??’ AND NOW() AND depdate BETWEEN ’??’ AND NOW() AND propid=??`

Comment: Please kindly assist me with the actual query. This is what I am looking for and i can then test it on my database

Comment: Date format would be 'YEAR-DAY-MONTH 00:00:00', can't assist you with the sums though because I don't know what sum you want.