# Matching value on date (year, month, day) but not time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14104364/1525840), it's suggested to use teh following syntax for matching against a given date, all day long.

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn 
    between '2014-08-25 00:00:00' 
    and '2014-08-25 23:59:59'
```

Besides the fact that we're missing the last second of each day, which practically perhaps isn't a large issue but principally might be a deal-breaker, I don't see why not use the simple expression below.

The matching is done with on a semi-open interval with the upper bound being exclusive (i.e. *fromAndInclusive <= date < toButNotInclusive*) and a date without any time specified is assumed to be at midnight (i.e. 00:00:00.000).

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn 
    between '2014-08-25' and '2014-08-26'
```

Please note that I'm not even close to be claiming any level of competence when it comes to SQL so this question shouldn't be been as pointing out any errors. I'm cocky otherwise but when it comes to DBs, I've been humbled once or twice.   :)

Comment: Why do you say you're missing the last second of each day?  2014-08-26 isn't *that* day :P

Comment: Once that last second ticks over it's a new day... There is no `'2014-08-25 24:00:00'`. However using between is not a good idea and you should use. `where DateColumn >='2014-08-25 00:00:00' and DateColumn<='2014-08-25 23:59:59'`

Comment: @Zane It would be better to use: `< '20140826'`

Comment: @Kritner I mean *the last second* but of **25th**, i.e. any time on form *2014-08-25 23:59:59.xxx*.

Comment: @Zane You're write that once the last second ticks over it's the next day. But it takes a second for that to happen and **that** is the time of **today** that we're missing from the comparison. Also, why isn't it a good idea to use *between/and*?

Comment: Use what @Lamak said, `WHERE DateColumn >= '20140825' AND DateColumn < '20140826'`. See this: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Comment: @Lamak or even when `Cast(dateColumn as date) = '2014-08-25'`

Comment: @Zane Yeah, but then you might negate the possibility of using an index on that column

Comment: @ypercube So the original answer that I'm linking to **is** missing a second, right? Yey! I got something right in SQL! Also - you should undelete your deleted reply. It's always good to see other approaches.

Comment: @Konrad Yes. But your 2nd query will have the same problem, in reverse. It will add the first point in time of the next day. `'2014-08-26'` and `'2014-08-26 00:00:00'` are the same thing.

Comment: @ypercube Just read the link you've provided. I think that's incorrect info. When I shoot the dates at my DB, it seems that the upper bound **is** exclusive. Not saying that one should use *between*. It might very well be evil. Just pointing out that in my DB, the interval is semi-open. Weird...

Comment: No, it's not. You are wrong. `BETWEEN` is inclusive, always. See the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55041/1).

Comment: @ypercube In that case, I can't explain why the match in my question doesn't include the post dated 26th at midnight... The fiddle came out empty. Did you save it before posting?   :(

Comment: @KonradViltersten It's not about "thinking" that it might be incorrect, [BETWEEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922(v=sql.100).aspx) **is** inclusive, it says so in the documentation: "BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than **or equal** to the value of begin_expression and less than **or equal** to the value of end_expression."

Comment: @Lamak I'm **not** saying you're wrong. I'm saying that I don't understand why I can't reproduce the behavior expected based on that definition.   :(   I'm very inexperienced with SQL.

Comment: @Konran Probably because the datetime stored in your database does not have a time part of exactly `00:00:00.000`. Or (the horror) you are not using datetime but a char column.

Comment: @ypercube Ah! There it was. The darned thing had a tiny, tiny tail of a few fractions of a second. Now I'm happy again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both will return incorrect results.

[Between](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187922.aspx) is **inclusive** at **both** ends so your first query

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn 
  between '2014-08-25 00:00:00' 
  and '2014-08-25 23:59:59'
```

will ignore anything in the last second of `2014-08-25` as you point out.

The second query you propose is too greedy. It will include anything at *exactly* midnight on the 26th i.e. `2014-08-26 00:00:00`.

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn 
  between '2014-08-25' and '2014-08-26'
```

To get the results you need you should use `>=` and `<` (as @Lamak) points out in the comments:

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn >= '2014-08-25' and DateColumn < '2014-08-26'.
```

Given the following data in the table:

```
2014-08-25 23:59:59
2014-08-25 23:59:59.500
2014-08-26 00:00:00
2014-08-26 00:00:00.500
2014-08-26 00:00:01
```

The first query matches just:

```
2014-08-25 23:59:59.000
```

The second matches:

```
2014-08-25 23:59:59.000
2014-08-25 23:59:59.500
2014-08-26 00:00:00.000 --this is wrong!
```

and finally the third (correctly) matches:

```
2014-08-25 23:59:59.000
2014-08-25 23:59:59.500
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Info
  where DateColumn >='2014-08-25 00:00:00' 
    and datecolumn<='2014-08-25 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My question is why not use the syntax. Also, you seem to have the same error that I've pointed out in my question. Would you like to check it again, please?

Comment: What error are you referring to? I'm a bit unclear on what you're trying to solve, if not just looking for another way to do the same query?

Comment: @Kritner He's missing e.g. 23:59:59.333. His query is equivalent to the first one. But the second one, that **I** am suggesting constituted an interval which is one second longer. His interval covers 86399 seconds, while mine stretches over 86400 seconds.

Comment: Why is this answer still here and why is is upvoted? It doesn't answer the question, it only has the same query as the OP has tried (and knew it's wrong).