# Mysql get records with specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table that contains a field named date of type timestamp. I would retrieve only rows that of a specific date.

My PHP script receive date in format dd-MM-YYYY

This is how I parse date for query:

```
$converted_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

This is my WHERE clause:

```
WHERE DATE(date) = '" . $converted_date . "' ORDER BY date DESC"
```

I always obtain an empty result.

Comment: First of all - `date` is a reserved mysql word, At least you should use backticks

Comment: @u_mulder (and upvoter) date is *not* a reserved word

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time)

> NEVER EVER use a selector like DATE(datecolumns) = '2012-12-24' - it is a performance killer:
>
> It will calculate DATE() for all rows, including those, that don't match

It is much faster to use

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59'
```

You would need to adjust your where clause to return all of the records between midnight and midnight of that day.

```
$converted_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
//$converted_date2 would equal that day up to 23:59:59
WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $converted_date . "' AND '.$converted_date2.' ORDER BY date DESC"
```

Although you could also use

```
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```