# Combine Union ALL with Inner Join Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, union

I have a problem how to combine the sql statements (inner join and union all. as a Newbie in SQL. Hopefully all members can help me to solve the problems.attached herewith the SQL. The leave_Trx and leave_History contain same values that need to be union. Thank you.

```
select m.name, t.startdt, t.enddt,t.noday,t.createdDT,
      (case when t.approveST = 'Y' then 'Approved' when t.approveST = 'N' then 'Not Approved' else 'Pending' end) as appST
      from leave_Trx t
      inner join leave_MType m on m.typeID = t.trxID
      inner join hr_personaldata b on b.pers_ID = @pers_ID
      where year(t.startdt) = @yyear
      and b.pers_ID = @pers_ID and b.pers_name LIKE '%'+@pers_name+'%'
      and b.pers_compID LIKE ''+@compID+''
      union all
      select * from leave_History h
      where year(h.startdt) = @yyear and h.status = 'A'
      ORDER BY t.startdt
```

Comment: Does the `leave_History` table have six columns?  What is your current output/error?

Comment: Don't use `where year(h.startdt) = @yyear`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time why you shouldn't.

Comment: the error is "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: You need to also select 6 columns from `leave_History`, and ideally the columns should be the same type in both parts of your `UNION` query (or the types should be coercible into one another).

Comment: leave_Trx and leave_History have 23 columns

Comment: Also, don't use `select *` but write out the columns.  Among other benefits, will help you ensure that that all your unions have compatible columns.

Comment: `leave_Trx` and `leave_History` may both have 23 columns, but it is your SELECT statements which define which are made available, and they must both match.

Comment: thank you to all suggestion, it work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select  t.pers_ID,t.startdt, t.enddt,t.noday,t.createdDT,
      (case when t.approveST = 'Y' then 'Approved' when t.approveST = 'N' then 'Not Approved' else 'Pending' end) as appST
      from leave_Trx t
      inner join leave_MType m on m.typeID = t.pers_ID
      inner join hr_personaldata l on l.pers_ID = @pers_ID
      where year(t.startdt) = @yyear and t.status = 'A'
      union all
      select h.pers_ID, h.startdt, h.enddt,h.noday,h.createdDT,
      (case when h.approveST = 'Y' then 'Approved' when h.approveST = 'N' then 'Not Approved' else 'Pending' end) as appST 
      from leave_History h
      inner join leave_MType m on m.typeID = h.pers_ID
      inner join hr_personaldata b on b.pers_ID = @pers_ID
      where year(h.startdt) = @yyear and h.status = 'A'
```