# Filter on date from datetime in query builder (CakePHP 3)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.8

I have a `datetime` field in my model. In a query I want to select all rows created on a specific day/date (the time doesn't matter). What is the simplest way of doing that in CakePHP 3.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104304/mysql-select-where-datetime-matches-day-and-not-necessarily-time), use of a [custom function to cast the column](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#custom-functions) with MySQL DATE() may slow your query down at scale. Besides, there's probably nothing simpler than plain arrays to build conditions:

```
$query = $this->YourTable->find()
    ->where([
        'date_field >=' => '2020-01-01 00:00:0', // Or pass a Time() object..
        'date_field <' => '2020-01-02 00:00:00',
    ]);
```

This kind of stuff is covered in the [Query Builder docs](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html).

Comment: Nice, thanks. And I used the default PHP DateTime object to get today and tomorrow at midnight.