# Simple mysql query with "AND" does not work, but each side or variations do

Tags: mysql

Having a hard time with this seemingly VERY simple mysql query:

This does not work (valid, but returns no rows):

```
select * from events where type = 'Disposition' AND startDT > '2012-01-01'
```

All of the following queries DO work off the same data:

```
select * from events where type = 'Eval' AND startDT > '2012-01-01'    
-- (change the value to Eval it works!)

select * from events where type = 'Disposition' AND addedDT > '2012-01-01' 
-- (search a different date field it works!)

select * from events where type = 'Disposition'  
-- (get rid of the AND it works!)

select * from events where startDT > '2012-01-01'   
-- (again, no AND it works!)
```

I have tried variations on the bad query, that also do NOT work:

```
select * from events where `type` = 'Disposition' AND `startDT` > '2012-01-01'
select * from events where `type` = 'Disposition' AND `startDT` > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
select events.* from events where `type` = 'Disposition' 
    AND `startDT` > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
```

(also tried variations on the date, lower case disposition)

I did not have an index on these fields, so I added an index on startDT, then type+startDT (addedDT has one).
NO DIFFERENCE.

startDT and addedDT are DATETIME fields.
type is varchar 30

Any ideas?

-- 
If this helps, here is the explain output:

BAD ONE:

```
explain select * FROM `events` WHERE `startDT` > '2012-01-11 00:00:01' AND `type` = "Disposition" limit 1000
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "events"    "range" "startDT,type"  "type"  "40"    NULL    "1" "Using where"
```

RIGHT SIDE:

```
explain select * FROM `events` WHERE `type` = "Disposition" limit 1000
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "events"    "ref"   "type"  "type"  "32"    "const" "13760" "Using where"
```

LEFT SIDE:

```
explain select * FROM `events` WHERE `startDT` > '2012-01-11 00:00:01' limit 1000
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "events"    "range" "startDT"   "startDT"   "8" NULL    "13760" "Using where"
```

SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
    `id` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `pk` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `addedDT` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `startDT` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
    INDEX `addedDT` (`addedDT`),
    INDEX `startDT` (`startDT`),
    INDEX `type` (`type`, `startDT`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=29407;
```

SAMPLE ROWS:

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `pk`, `addedDT`, `type`, `startDT`) VALUES ('FBF8CE96-AE86-36C6-3C27-E2AAD042476B', 29406, '2012-12-28 12:59:03', 'Disposition', '2012-12-28 12:59:00');
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `pk`, `addedDT`, `type`, `startDT`) VALUES ('12577DB6-9B22-FA73-89BD-E2A5C1764B6D', 29405, '2012-12-28 12:53:32', 'Disposition', '2012-12-28 12:53:00');
```

Comment: Hi, can you post an create table?

Comment: It is not fetching any rows because it doesn't have any row with `type='Disposition'`

Comment: Sorry for not formatting (i get votes down for that??  that makes it not a valid question??).      Sashi - please re-read, the query for type='Disposition' *IS* working, 8440 rows returned.

Comment: @ScottSzretter Could you give us the schema of the table, and an (existing) sample row that isn't found and should be? Preferably as an SQLfiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but have you verified that there are in fact rows that match both of those criteria at once?  You haven't said so in your question.

Comment: @ScottSzretter could you provide us with a schema from your table? It could really help, perhaps your are using the wrong data type in your query.

Comment: YES, I demonstrate above that both sides of they query work on their own - the date or the string query.    I just added the schema and two sample rows from the data that should be found using that query.  These rows ARE found if I query just 'Disposition' or > '2012-01-01'

Comment: For the heck of it, I restarted all my services, and it's working now!! ??   Not sure how to explain why that fixed it.

Comment: @ScottSzretter Does it work when you add DATE to the where clause or does it work with your original query?

Comment: @ScottSzretter great that you solved your question. Very strange that a reset helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column `startDT` is of date type in your table, try comparing date as-

```
select * from events where `type` = 'Disposition' AND `startDT` > DATE('2012-01-01');
```

Comment: Good idea, but no, it returned 0 rows.  Just to clarify, select count(*) from events where `startDT` > DATE('2012-01-01'); returns 15572 and select count(*) from events where `type` = 'Disposition' returns 8440 rows.   (you can see in my original post 2 sample rows that contain both Disposition and a 2012 date.

Comment: you had checked data in your table for the given constraints?? because this syntax is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add date to where clause

```
WHERE `startDT` >  DATE('2012-01-01')
```

OR

```
WHERE DATE(`startDT`) >  ('2012-01-01')
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c879/7

A similar post can be found here [How to select date from datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)