# How to get ID where it's most hits grouping by date in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have this table like this:

```
AdID | Hits | CreatedOn
1, 20, 2013-08-28 18:18:42
2, 12, 2013-08-28 13:34:42
3, 12, 2013-08-27 11:34:42
4, 14, 2013-08-27 02:34:42
5, 12, 2013-08-26 11:34:42
6, 12, 2013-08-26 02:34:42
```

I want to the result will be like this:

```
1, 20, 2013-08-28
4, 14, 2013-08-27
5, 12, 2013-08-26
```

Basically it will select the most hist of each date and if it's the HITS same it will pick top of AdID

How do I do this in mySQL?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: you need to group by hits then group by date order by most recent date

Comment: See also: [How to select `date` from `datetime` column?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1754411/1935077)

Answer (score 3):

This will perform a little slower since you need to extract time from date but will give you the result you need.

```
SELECT  a.AdID, a.Hits, DATE(a.CreatedON) CreatedON
FROM        tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DATE(CreatedON) CreatedON,
                    MAX(Hits) Hits 
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY DATE(CreatedON)
        ) b ON a.Hits = b.Hits AND  
                DATE(a.CreatedON) = b.CreatedON
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5963/5)

Comment: This will give two rows for a date if they have the same number of hits.

Comment: @jbaylina exactly. they have the same number and the most hit of the day.

Comment: The question sais to take only the one with lower AdID.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5963/11)**

```
SELECT  a.AdID, a.Hits, DATE(a.CreatedOn) CreatedON
FROM tableName a
WHERE a.AdID = (SELECT b.adID
                FROM tableName b
                WHERE DATE(b.CreatedOn) = DATE(a.CreatedOn)
                ORDER BY b.Hits DESC, b.adID ASC
                LIMIT 1)
```

Result:

```
| ADID | HITS |                     CREATEDON |
-----------------------------------------------
|    1 |   20 | August, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|    4 |   14 | August, 27 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|    5 |   12 | August, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to `GROUP BY` hits and, then pick the lowest or highest ID, so you will need 2 things: a group and ordering:

```
SELECT AdID FROM table GROUP BY Hits ORDER BY AdID ASC LIMIT 1
```

This will give you the lowest AdID for the group with the most Hits. If you want the highest AdID, you need to switch `ASC` with `DESC` ofcource

Comment: but this will only return 1 row!!

Comment: Need grouping by date NOT hits ... then it picks the MAX of that hits and the id of that MAX hits.

Comment: If you need grouping by date, this will not work; it is impossible in 1 query, without subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName T1
WHERE ( SELECT count(*)
        FROM TableName T2
        WHERE      (T2.Hits < T1.Hits OR (T2.Hits=T1.Hits AND T2.AdID < T1.AdID)) 
               AND  DATE(T2.CreatedOn)=DATE(T1.CreatedOn)
      ) < 1
```

This way you can select the 2nd, 3rd, the top 3 for each date, etc.

Check this interesting link: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/08/08/how-to-select-the-nth-greatestleastfirstlast-row-in-sql/