# Get rows that are past due from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to get all rows from a database table that are past due and only the ones that are past due.

The table includes a column that is titled `due_date` and is formatted as a `datetime`

`Past Due` stands for anything with a `due_date` prior to todays date. So for example, if the due date was 04/25/2014 and todays date was 04/26/2014 it would be considered overdue.

My code is as follows:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('practice', array('due_date' => date('Y-m-d')));

return $query->result();
```

But wouldn't that return everything due today? Not quite what I want.

A row would look something like this for the due_date column

```
2014-04-23 00:00:00
```

Comment: Try, `array('due_date' => date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :**

```
 $query=$this->db
             ->where('DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <',"date('Y-m-d')")
             ->get('practice');
```

Source: [[How to select date from datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column])

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search gives me a solution where this should be possible:

```
$query = $this->db->where('practice', array('due_date <' => date('Y-m-d')))->get();
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('practice', array('DATE_FORMAT(due_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <' => date('Y-m-d')));
```