# Search by month and day mqsql

Tags: mysql, datetime, search

i have table messages with column date (format DATETIME)
how i can search messages where date = xxxx-05-09 ?

```
select * from messages where date = 'xxxx-05-09';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select date from datetime column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select * from messages where Extract(Month from date) = 5 and Extract(Day from date) = 9;
```

Comment: 15:51:16 select * from messages where Extract(Month from date) == 5 and Extract(Day from date) == 9 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 5 and Extract(Day from date) == 9' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: @karpengold        I had by mistake put == instead of = . Try it now

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DATE_FORMAT function:

```
select * from messages where DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") = 'xxxx-05-09';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

DATE function can help

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE MONTH(date) = '05' AND DAY(date) = '09';
```