# Select Date From DateTime In Query - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm having one event table. In which, `due date` of event is being stored in `datetime` format. But, due to some change of requirement, now we need to show only `date` (excluding time) from `due date` column.

**Event** (Table)

```
id | user_id | description |       due_date          | is_completed

1      8        My Event1    2016-08-09 19:16:00          0
2      8        My Event2    2016-08-09 19:53:00          0
```

I wanted to show all event in date wise. Like all event under `2016-08-09`.

So, I tried with this query.

```
$upcoming_events = Events::find()->select(['due_date'])->distinct()
           ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->users->getId(),'is_completed'=> 0 ])
           ->andWhere(['>=','due_date',date("Y-m-d")])
          ->orderBy(['due_date'=>'ASC'])->limit(5)->all();
```

But, now 2 dates are being selected as `2016-08-09 19:16:00` & `2016-08-09 19:53:00`. Since, date part is not being fetched from select statement. It is showing 2 times same date.

***var_dump($upcoming_events);***

```
[1] => app\Events Object
  (
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [due_date] => 2016-08-09 19:16:00
        )
  )

[2] => app\Events Object
(

  [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
  (
      [due_date] => 2016-08-09 19:53:00
  )
)
```

How can I retrieve only date from date time field to get only 1 date in Yii2 Query.

Any help/hint/suggestions is appreciable.

Comment: [Refer this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)

Comment: Do you need to print the date or you need to check in query?

Comment: $due_date = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime($model->due_date)); then pass $due_date into query

Comment: Hi @RajkumarR : I want to print date and even pass this date to find out all the events related to that particular date.

Comment: @InsaneSkull: Is there any way to select part of date in datetime field in yii2 active query.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use only the date part

```
 upcoming_events = Events::find()->select('date(due_date) as due_date')->distinct()
       ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->users->getId(),'is_completed'=> 0 ])
       ->andWhere(['>=','due_date',date("Y-m-d")])
      ->orderBy(['due_date'=>'ASC'])->limit(5)->all();
```

Comment: Thank You Scais. This Is What I Was Looking For.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this example,

```
YourModelName::find()->where(['date(timestamp)' => php('Y-m-d')]->one();
```

Here date will be fetched from timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query by which you can get the converted date from timestamp using Yii2 model query.

```
$upcoming_events     = Yii::$app->$db->createCommand('SELECT  count(DISTINCT(date(due_date))) as edate FROM event_master')
    ->queryAll();


    foreach ($upcoming_events as $upevnts){
    echo $upevnts['edate'];
}
```

Comment: No *vijay* bhai. How to use `select date(due_date)` in yii2 query. This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for `date(due_date)` in active query. I didn't get. So, I used **Command Builder**.

And, It worked.

```
$upcoming_events_date = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT DISTINCT date(due_date) FROM events WHERE user_id = :user_id AND is_completed=:is_completed AND  due_date > :due_date ORDER BY due_date ASC LIMIT 0,5")
                                   ->bindParam(':user_id',Yii::$app->users->getId())
                                    ->bindParam(':is_completed',0)
                                    ->bindParam(':due_date',date('Y-m-d'))
                                    ->queryAll();
```

But, even though it works. I would like to know solution in **Active query**.

Comment: मदद कर.. खुशाल रह.. @Nana

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` Exactly @vijaynathji