# Spring Data JPA - custom @Query with "@Param Date" doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I create custom query for getting Invoice data by **Date**, but it returns **null**. I'm sure that I set exactly the same Date for query that exists in database.

I use custom query because I want more advance query to write. But issue exist in this simple query. Here is my sample code:

```
@Query("select i from Invoice i where " +
        "i.expirationDate = :expDate")
Invoice findCompanyInvoiceByDate(@Param("expDate") Date expDate);
```

I tried this code but it does not work also:

```
 Invoice findByExpirationDate(Date expirationDate);
```

I also tried to add `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` before Date and @Param but result is null.

Comment: does your Date involves also time, hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds etc? Are you sure these values are exact the sames?

Comment: Can you add the details of date format present in database and dat eformat expDate from java side ?

Comment: In MySQL database I set field as "datetime". And values are exact same when I retrieve it from database.

Comment: I'm using "java.util.Date"

Comment: try putting @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) on the field in the entity

Comment: Error appears "..for column expiration_date. Found: datetime, expected: date". But I need column with "datetime" type.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` in your date column. If that still not enough (still return null), add `columnDefinition` in `@Column` annotation as well.

Full working example [is here](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/tree/so-40613171) (*Note the so-40613171 branch. Sorry for weird repository name, and class naming. It uses by a lot of case study*). Rough example:

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "birth_date", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
  private Date birthDate;

  // Other fields, getter setter, etc.
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository 
extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

  @Query("from Employee e where e.birthDate = :birthDate")
  List<Employee> findEmployeeDataByBirthDate(@Param("birthDate") Date birthDate);
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Company companySun = companyRepository.save(new Company(42, "Sun microsystems"));
Company companyGoogle = companyRepository.save(new Company(43, "Google"));

employeeRepository.save(new Employee(101, "James", "Gosling", dateFormat.parse("1970-01-01 17:05:05"), companySun));
employeeRepository.save(new Employee(102, "Paul", "Sheridan", dateFormat.parse("1970-01-01 17:05:05"), companySun));
employeeRepository.save(new Employee(103, "Patrick", "Naughton", dateFormat.parse("1970-01-01 17:05:05"), companySun));

employeeRepository.save(new Employee(201, "Lary", "Page", dateFormat.parse("1970-01-01 17:01:05"), companyGoogle));
employeeRepository.save(new Employee(202, "Sergey", "Brin", dateFormat.parse("1970-01-02 17:02:05"), companyGoogle));
```

**Test Code Snippet**

```
@Test
public void employeService_findByBirthDate() throws ParseException {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    List<Employee> result = this.employeeService.findByBirthDate(dateFormat.parse("1970-01-01 17:05:05"));

    Assert.assertEquals(3, result.size());
}
```

If you run this, the test is passed.

HTH

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I don't know why. Surely, this is very helpful example which should be taken into consideration, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the date as a String and used `nativeQuery = true`. It worked well for me.

```
@Query(value ="select * from table st where st.created_date >= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<YourObject> findAllByCreatedDate(@Param("createdDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) String createdDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that was useful for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378572/2230060).

If you use "date" type, I think the code from question should work, but for "datetime" you should use "between" in query or something similar. I found the solution that works for me, and this is the code:

```
@Query("select i from Invoice i where " +
        "i.expirationDate >= :todayMidnight and i.expirationDate < :tomorowMidnight " +
        "order by expirationDate DESC")
List<Invoice> findCompanyInvoiceByDate(@Param("todayMidnight") Date todayMidnight, @Param("tomorowMidnight") Date tomorowMidnight);
```