# Optimal Index on datetime colum for queries on day

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, indexing

I have the following table with roughly 400 million rows. I have to perform `SELECT` queries on this table, generally involving `WHERE` clause on `Date_create`column.

**The key is** that most of **my queries are on full days** (not taking into account hours and seconds)

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID_num         | bigint(45)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Content        | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| User_ID        | bigint(24)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Location       | varchar(70)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Date_create    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Would there be a significant increase in performance in:

1. Creating a new column `Day_create` which would be of `DATE` type, (not DATETIME) and having an index on this column.

As opposed to:

2. Having an index on the `Date_create` column of type `DATETIME` .

Answer (score 2):

You could have an index on `Date_create` that works well, as long as you take the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1754411/1136950) and query the field optimally (not using the `DATE()` function).

This way, you get the best of both worlds: fast `SELECT` queries and no extra storage required for an extra column.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't bother with an extra column.

But do be careful how you formulate queries.  Otherwise, the query may fail to use the index.

```
WHERE Date_create >= '2017-02-01'
  AND Date_create  < '2017-02-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

is a simple, clear, leap-year-proof, datatype-proof, way to fetch all rows for this February.  (Variations on it work fine for `1 DAY`, `36 HOUR`, `2 WEEK`, etc.)

You have not said what the rest of the `WHERE` clause looks like.  This is also important, especially for 400M rows.  If, for example, you want the yesterday's data for location 'abcd':

```
WHERE Location = 'abcd'
  AND Date_create >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND Date_create  < CURDATE()

INDEX(Location, Date_create) -- in this order!
```

`'2017-02-01'` and `'2017-02-01 00:00:00'` are identical values; I prefer the former since it is shorter.  This applies whether you are comparing against `DATETIME` or `DATE`.

If you need to discuss further, please provide the query/queries you need to discuss.  (Other indexes may be needed; single-day and day-range may work differently, etc.)