# How to create query for sum of particular months and same years data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on one erp where i want to create pdf of each month of every user.

for that i have some data in mysql. i am attaching image of my table with data.

In pdf there will some fields should be display like particular user's this years net_salary, how many days he worked for this year etc.

For that basically i have to use SUM(column_name) with some conditions, but i cant get logic that if user will have 2018's 12 months data into database but user want only october month's salary_slip.

So now i want to display his 2018's SUM(net_salary) but till october months only. November and december's data should not be there in calculation.

I dont know how to create query for this.

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put query having the dates inside a condition.

Example, if you want the sum between the months of January and October:

```
SELECT SUM(net_salary) FROM `your_table` WHERE pay_from > '2018-01-01' AND pay_to < '2018-10-31'
```

Or by using BETWEEN...AND

```
SELECT SUM(net_salary) FROM `your_table` WHERE pay_from BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-10-31'
```

See more [How to select date from datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)