# I cant query a column that is Datetime using the year, month and seconds

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My site was built with WordPress and I have the following case:
The table I want to query is the `wp_posts` and the column to be targeted is the `post_date` which is of the time `Datetime` (not `Date` and I cant change it because of WordPress's convenience).

How want to fire a sql query that will give me all the details about an event posted on a specific date that will come from a calendar.

I tried this:

```
$date = new DateTime(2019-07-03);

$date_format = $date->format("Y-m-d");

$request = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date = ".$date_format);

$result = $request->fetch()
```

If I `var_dump()` the `$dateformat` I can see the data, however, my `$result` shows nothing.
I then concluded that it will never show anything because in table, the dates also have times.

So, how can I get those details if I only have year, month, day, and not the hours?

Comment: If you are using wordpress, to get the post you can use wp_query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 3):

Dates are considerated as string in SQL. You must use quotes :

```
$request = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_date = "'.$date_format .'"');
```

By the way, yes if you have datetime columns, you need to query in other way, using BETWEEN or simply :

```
$date_format_next = $date->add(1, 'day')->format('Y-m-d');
$request = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM posts 
                WHERE post_date >= "'.$date_format .'"' 
                  AND post_date < "'.$date_format_next .'"');
```

Comment: As mentioned before, this wont work because we are using date format in year, month and day, when in the database the records are store with currentTimeStamp

Comment: I just posted an answer to my own question and hope you can let me know if perhaps that is not a good practice. I will still up vote yours though because it looks logical as well, though longer.

Comment: It's not a good practice, LIKE query will take more time. Look here if you are interested in performances issues : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column/30378572#30378572

Comment: There is just a syntax error in your answer that am struggling to figure out. Problem a quote missing somewhere. But I already marked the answer as useful

Answer (score 0):

After browsing through w3schools I ended up concluding that I can use the sql search.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_date` LIKE "%2019-07-03%"
```

My query works now

Answer (score 0):

Your column post_date is a datetime field and  I found the requested query has only the date value so you can use this query as:

```
$request =$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE(post_date) = '$date_format'");
```