# How can I filter the timestamp only using the date?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, filtering

I have a table with participants and their timestamps.
I built a filter and wanted to search for the date (e.g. 2021-01-24) in the timestamp, but that doesn't work because the datas can only be found, when I search with the time included (e.g. 2021-01-24 10:56:46)

So I would like to find a way where I can search for the date and all participants which took part on that specific day show up.

I tried it with the LIKE %xx% command but that didn't work.
And i am new to PHP and really need it for my school project.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to search on? A `datetime` column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select date from datetime column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754411/how-to-select-date-from-datetime-column)

Comment: Do you mean my column in the database? I have the type=timestamp

My Code for the filter is:
if (count($_POST)>0 && $_POST["R"]!="") {
  $sql = "
                SELECT * FROM tbl_teilnehmer
    WHERE(
     RegZeitpunkt='" . $_POST["R"] . "'
    )
            ";
} 
else {
  $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_teilnehmer
 ";
}
$antwort = $conn->query($sql)or die("Fehler in der Query: " . $conn->error . "<br>" . $sql);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only wanting to search for dates try the [MySQL `date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function like so.

```sql
select * from table where date(timestamp_col)=?
```

This will compare explicitly the date component of the timestamp rather than the full timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Try These For Changing Timestamp Format And Show User Side or Frontend**

```
date_format('2022-12-04 19:53:05','D M Y');//date like Fri Des 2022
             or
date_format('2022-12-04 19:53:05','d-m-Y'); //date like 04-12-2022
             or
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2022-12-04 19:53:05'));
```

**Example**

```
<?php
$full_date = '2022-12-04 19:53:05';
$formated_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($full_date));
echo $formated_date;
//output 04-12-2022
?>
```